flutter: build_runner files missing abstract class and map
So I'm new to flutter and I am using build_runner along with cloud_firestore_odm, json_annotation and json_serializable to auto generate some files for firebase and firestore in my flutter project. It works perfectly in the first project i included it in, but now I tried to include it in a brand new project, and the generated .g.dart file is missing one abstract class and a map for the JsonSerializableGenerator functionality.
Here is the model file I'm trying to generate a file for:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore_odm/cloud_firestore_odm.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';
// Define the User class
@JsonSerializable(converters: firestoreJsonConverters)
class User {
  String id;
  String? email; // Optional in TypeScript, nullable in Dart
  UserType? userType; // Optional in TypeScript, nullable in Dart
  String? name;
  String? phone;
  List<String>? locations;
  int? birthday; // Optional in TypeScript, nullable in Dart
  LoginProvider loginProvider;

  // Constructor
  User({
    required this.id,
    this.email,
    this.userType,
    this.name,
    this.birthday,
    this.locations,
    this.phone,
    required this.loginProvider,
  });

  bool get shouldWelcomeUser {
    return name == null;
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}

@Collection<User>('users') ///[users] is the name of the collection in Firestore.
final usersRef = UserCollectionReference();

// Define the UserType enum
enum UserType { user, admin }

// Define the LoginProvider enum
enum LoginProvider { email, google, apple }

It's an exact copy of what's working in my other project. But the generated user.g.dart file in my new project is missing the following abstract class and map which is being generated just fine in my other project:
const _$UserFieldMap = <String, String>{
  'id': 'id',
  'email': 'email',
  'userType': 'userType',
  'name': 'name',
  'phone': 'phone',
  'locations': 'locations',
  'birthday': 'birthday',
  'loginProvider': 'loginProvider',
};

// ignore: unused_element
abstract class _$UserPerFieldToJson {
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? id(String instance) => instance;
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? email(String? instance) => instance;
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? userType(UserType? instance) => _$UserTypeEnumMap[instance];
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? name(String? instance) => instance;
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? phone(String? instance) => instance;
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? locations(List<String>? instance) => instance;
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? birthday(int? instance) => instance;
  // ignore: unused_element
  static Object? loginProvider(LoginProvider instance) =>
      _$LoginProviderEnumMap[instance]!;
}

I'm using the following dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  firebase_core: ^2.27.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.17.9
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.9
  cloud_firestore_odm: ^1.0.0-dev.84
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.11
  transparent_image: ^2.0.1
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.2
  flutter_html_all: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^6.0.0
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: any

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.8
  cloud_firestore_odm_generator: ^1.0.0-dev.85
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"

